# UIPickerView not appearing

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I have `DrinkVolumePickerController.swift` where I'm trying to keep the delegate and datasource logic to keep them out of my ViewController

```
import UIKit

class DrinkVolumePickerController: NSObject, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    var quantities: [(label: String, ml: Int)] = [("Pint", 568), ("Can", 330)]

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return quantities.count
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return quantities[row].label + " - " + String(quantities[row].ml)
    }

}
```

In my ViewController I have

```
import UIKit

class AddDrinkViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var drinkVolumeControl: UIPickerView! = {
        let view = UIPickerView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let controller = DrinkVolumePickerController()
        view.delegate = controller
        view.dataSource = controller

        return view
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(drinkVolumeControl)
        view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
    }
}
```

When I run this in the simulator I don't see the Picker, but I can see it in the DebugViewHeirarchy.

If I move all the logic back into the ViewController and change the `delegate` and `datasource` to `self` then it loads fine.

I just don't get why it's not working having them in an external file?

Comment: The pickerView is not meant to be it’s own delegate or data source. You can isolate the code by putting it in an extension to your view controller.

Comment: In your view controller code you are setting the pickerView to be the delegate of your view controller’s view, which will not achieve anything. The view controller should be the delegate and data source of the picker view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a memory management problem.

Move the line:

```
let controller = DrinkVolumePickerController()
```

to be a property of your `AddDrinkViewController` instead of being a local variable inside `drinkVolumeControl`.